# Making a conditional TapGestureRecognizer?

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I want to return to my initial Scene if the user taps the screen after the ball hits the ground. How would I make a conditional statement so that I can tap the screen to return to the home page?

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    if ( contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask & groundCategory ) == groundCategory || ( contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask & groundCategory ) == groundCategory {   //Ball hits ground
        //Return to home screen if you tap the screen after the game ends
        gameEnded = true
    }
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
     if gameEnded {
          //How do I restart my Game?
     }
}
```